# onActivityResult not called immediately after photo is taken in Google nexus s 4g

Tags: android, nexus-s

I am calling Camera intent from this code :

```
void opencamera(){
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = Common.getOutputMediaFileUri(Common.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE,
                CameraActivity.this);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent,
                Common.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type, Context context) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    File mediaStorageDir;
    File mediaStorageProfileDir;

    if (isSdPresent() == true) {

        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath(),
                "test/XYZ");

        mediaStorageProfileDir = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath(),
                "test/XYZ");

    } else {

        mediaStorageDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
                "test/XYZ");
        mediaStorageProfileDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
                "test/XYZ");

    }

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        mediaStorageDir.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    } else if (mediaStorageDir.exists()) {

    }

    if (!mediaStorageProfileDir.exists()) {
        mediaStorageProfileDir.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    } else if (mediaStorageProfileDir.exists()) {

    }

    boolean setWritable, setwritable = false;

    setWritable = mediaStorageDir.setWritable(true, false);
    setwritable = mediaStorageProfileDir.setWritable(true, false);

    Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "mediaStorageDir ::" + setWritable
                    + " mediaStorageProfileDir :: " + setwritable,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  HH:mm a")
            .format(new Date());

    File mediaFile = null;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "test" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    } else {

        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

this code is working on Moto E, Moto G , Samsung Duos devices, but this same code is not working on Google Nexus s 4g(version 4.1.0),  In Nexus s it opens camera but after taking photo it not allow me to click tick and because of that OnActivityResult is not called.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult fire", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    if (requestCode == Common.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        try {

            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "result code : " + resultCode + " data :: " + data
                            + "request code ::" + requestCode,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "onActivity result file URI :::" + fileUri,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (fileUri != null) {

                    this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(fileUri, null);
                    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

                    try {

                        // create high quality bitmap

                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                                fileUri.toString());
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                                .getBitmap(cr, fileUri);

                        // rotate bitmap.
                        bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);

                        imgUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        // RLcamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            img_categoryedit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            img_categoryedit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            ShowWindowPopUp();
                            Visible_InVisible(true);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "resultCode cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written onactivity result...

Comment: have you checked whether the debugger is going into onActivity result or not... If it is going please check resultcode and request code.. it might be diffrent..

Comment: he is not coming in onActivity result, debugger is not coming